# How do you figure out what hyperbolic tilings are compatible with a given surface?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces, conformal-geometry, tiling

By the uniformization theorem, any Riemann surface $H$ is conformally equivalent to one of constant curvature. Let's say that $H$ is conformally equivalent to a surface with curvature $-1$.

Therefore, the hyperbolic plane is a conformal universal cover of $H$. For any tiling on $H$, there is a corresponding tiling in the hyperbolic plane.

My question is, how do you figure out for which tilings in the hyperbolic plane there exists a tiling in $H$ that corresponds to it.

EDIT: For example, perhaps your surface is made by sewing together polygons, and the tiling in question is a {m,n} tiling. (This in particular makes the problem a computational decision problem.)

Comment: Abstract answer: When the tiling is invariant under the (hyperbolic) covering group. But maybe you have a more specific situation in mind?

Comment: @WimC I was thinking of a sphere with 4 disks removed in particular.

Comment: The abstract answer applies to your special case without change.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was thinking more of, say, an algorithm. How do you calculate the hyperbolic covering group?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could add more clarity and explicitness to your question. Asking "how do you figure out" is not very explicit. But I'll try to give more details. By basic covering space theory, the covering group is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $H$. Furthermore, if you represent $H$ by a particular polygon with sides identified in pairs, you get an explicit presentation of the fundamental group, and an explicit embedding of that polygon as a fundamental domain of the covering group with explicit side pairing isometries.

Comment: @LeeMosher isn't the fundamental group a topological construct? I thought that the compatible tilings would depend on the geometry of the surface, not just the topology.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the relationship between covering space theory and the fundamental group, with a particular emphasis on learning the isomorphism between the fundamental group and the covering transformation group (deck transformation group). Without knowing that, my comments (and any answer) won't be of much help to you.